# How do I convert a REST HttpRequest captured via a web proxy tool into a link a user can click?

Tags: rest, httprequest

I have used a [proxy tool](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project)  to capture a certain REST HttpRequest.  The request is a HTTP PUT command followed by an extremely long REST link containing specific data that gets sent to the server.

In the proxy tool it looks something like this:

Header

```
PUT http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/rest/blah/blah/.../ HTTP/1.1
Host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-language: en-us, en:q=0.5
Proxy Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/plugins/blah/blah
Content-length: 11156
Cookie: JSESSIONID=<really long alpha numeric>
```

Body:

```
{"links":{"self":"/rest/plugins/1.0/blah/blah.....
     ... 
     ... lots and lots of JSON text
}

}
```

So the proxy tool has been helpful in identifying what the request looks like.

But the only way to generate this request is by clicking a button on the webpage.  I would like to send exact same request on my own (like creating a custom link that when clicked generates a similar request to the one shown above).  How do I do this?

Also, anything I type in the web browser URL area automatically is a "GET".  How do I force a PUT?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If your GUI uses HTML then in order to send a `PUT` request, your have to create a new XHR with javascript, and send that. With HTML only you have to add a form with a submit button, and some workaround about the http method.

Comment: @inf3rno - I have modified the question to be more clear.  Basically I am confused how to recreate a captured XMLHttpRequest in the form of a user-defined link.

Answer (score 0):

> Cookie: JSESSIONID=

This clearly indicates that the API you want to use is not a REST API, because it violates the stateless constraint of REST.

> How do I force a PUT?

Probably you don't have a way to do that. It depends on the security settings of the web API. If you want to do this with AJAX from the browser, and your domain is different from the APIs domain, then you need a CORS header from the API, which allows your domain to read cross origin responses. By PUT the browsers sends a preflight first, and if it cannot read the response, it will never send the real PUT. Security policy and other headers can block XSS in the browser, so you probably don't have a way to do this from browser.

You can do this from your server by copying the request details and catching the session id somehow.

If the API allows access to 3rd party clients, then I suggest you to contact with them. If not, then you 99% that you won't be able to do this.